# Black screen on Debian VirtualBox

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am using Debian as guest in VirtualBox. 
It was working without any problems. 
But when I install another machine (another Debian) in my vBox,
the first Debian does not boot; it freezes in black screen. 
When I enter the first Debian OS in recovery mode,
I can list my directories with `ls`. 
But when I try to run it, I get the black screen. 
How can I fix this problem?

- OS host: Windows 11
- OS guest: Debian 11
- VirtualBox version: 7.0

Comment: Help you to allow us to help you. OS, versions, logs, loaded modules...